# Passing transformation rules from frontend to backend

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angular, rule-engine

I have some javascript objects in angular frontend that corresponds to headers of CSV file uploaded. I need to pass this object with some type of transformations to backend as JSON. The object looks like this:

```
{
   name: "fieldOne",
   type: "string",
   metadata:{

   } 
}
```

When I read the .csv file in the backend, I want to apply these transformations specified in the front-end side. for example:

**PSEUDO-CODE**

```
for each row found in CSV file.
  if fieldOne.value <= 3 then fieldOne.value = 0
  ese fieldOne.value <=6 then fieldOne.value = 1
  .... etc.
```

These transformations can be specified by the user in the frontend.

Do you have any ideas that how to pass this rules on the post to my node.js backend and then execute these functions for each value of the matches field?

Comment: Could you be a little more clear on how these transformations would be specified in the JSON format?

Comment: @DerekBrown this is exactly the point. I don't have an idea how to do that and how to execute in backend side

Comment: It is just entirely unclear to me what type of transformations you actually want to support?